# Collision shape and Model problem

Tags: physics, xna-4.0

I used BEPUphysics for my XNA 4.0 game , the problem is that I load my model.fbx from into the game then add it to the space of physics engine , but when I change the scaling matrix of my Model then collision did not work , if I keep model scale the same then my model response to collision and every thing look good !

some says to me that your collision shape (it's often box ) that bound your model have to be changed also if the Model changed ? is this true ? (If yes !!! what is this ????)

Comment: The physics calculations are performed on collision shapes because they are simpler and therefore faster for collision calculations then the polygon mesh. Since the collision is only calculated based on the collision shapes scaling the vertices will not effect the collision. So you have to resize the collision shape, too.

Comment: thank you sharethis, 
So why when scale my model the collision not working ?? if you say that I have to resize the collision , the problem is when I making my model bigger no when resize it ?? 

ex : Model.transform== matrix.scale(1f); // work 
Model.transform = matrix.scale(5f) or (2f) or whatever any number bigger than 1f it's not working ?? 

how to solve that problem in my Engine . I just need steps.

Comment: Somehow you have to find a fitting bounding box (collision shape). Depending on your mesh, a cube or a sphere or a cylinder or whatever will fit better. But anyway you have to find its dimensions depending on the mesh size. Just redo the dimensions calculation each time the mesh scale changes. By the way, please avoid redundant question marks and format code using \` and \`.

Comment: thank sharethis , the last think  is that how " redo the dimensions calculation each time the mesh scale changes " how to do this ?? the problem is that I don't know how resize the dimension of my collision box according to mesh changes !! this is exactly my problem sharethis :(

Comment: Sorry but that depends on your physics engine which I never heard of. You should look for a documentation.

Comment: sharethis :) I will never forget your help thanks.
any way , I looked at the Doc , but it's high and not low in details :) . By the way , I will go around and see ! .

Comment: Do you change the scale of your model throughout the game? or just after loading? If it's the latter, then scale your model before adding it to the BEPU space.

Comment: @borrillis , thank you for response :) , I have done it , but the problem right now is how to make my character move in the world - physics side is done and it's collide with wold - all I have to do is make the player move when press "W".

Comment: @MohammadAhmed That's great, can you post how you fixed it as an answer so everyone can benefit? Movement you can find in the XNA samples, if not, I'd open another question for that.

Comment: yeah , I used convex hull and transform it with any collapsible model as simple as that !!

1 : I import all my models
2 : I create mesh from each model 
3 : I create convex hull entity by the mesh I created before 
4 : When Draw the Models in the Draw methode send the convex hull transformation matrix according with the model matrix .